# wstring -> LPCWSTR in ShellExecute give me error LNK2028 & LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, wstring, lnk2019

Hello I'm programming in Visual C++ 2010 (spanish) with UNICODE and /clr. I have a header file called "fileFuncs.h":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

void callSystem(string sCmd){
std::wstring stemp = s2ws(sCmd);
LPCWSTR params = stemp.c_str();

    ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /S /C ",params,NULL,SW_HIDE); 
}
```

But when I compile give me these errors:

- error LNK2028: refers to the
  unresolved symbol (token)  (0A0004A5)
  "extern "C" struct HINSTANCE__ *
  **stdcall ShellExecuteW(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const    *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?ShellExecuteW@@$$J224YGPAUHINSTANCE_*@@PAUHWND*_@@PB_W111H@Z)
  in the function "void __cdecl
  callSystem(class
  std::basic_string,class
  std::allocator >)"
  (?callSystem@@$$FYAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@
- error LNK2019: external symbol
  "extern "C" struct HINSTANCE__ *
  **stdcall ShellExecuteW(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?ShellExecuteW@@$$J224YGPAUHINSTANCE_*@@PAUHWND*_@@PB_W111H@Z)
  unresolved referred to in "void
  __cdecl callSystem(class std::basic_string,classstd::allocator)"
  function
  (?callSystem@@$$FYAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

Is some type of configuration?

Comment: Are you including Shell32.lib in your link?

Comment: I'm a newbie in C++. How I link Shell32.lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer, Properties, Linker, Input.  Add shell32.lib to the Additional Dependencies setting.

Beware that there's little point in compiling this code with the /clr option, you didn't write any managed code.  The equivalent of ShellExecute() function is Process::Start().

Answer (score 1):

On a side note: you do realize that you do not need to convert from `std::string` to `std::wstring` manually in this situation, right?  Like most API functions with string parameters, ShellExecute() has both Ansi and Unicode flavors available.  Let the OS do the conversion for you:

```
#include <string> 

void callSystem(std::string sCmd)
{
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /S /C ", sCmd.c_str(), NULL, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: `ShellExecuteA()` is the Ansi version, `ShellExecuteW()` is the Unicode version. `ShellExecuteA()` calls `ShellExecuteW()` internally, converting Ansi strings to Unicode as needed. `ShellExecute()` is an alias that maps to either `ShellExecuteA()` or `ShellExecuteW()` depending on whether the project is compiled wth `UNICODE` defined or not. In your example, it is (or else `ShellExecute()` would not accept `wchar_t*` data). Most Win32 API functions that work on string data use this same kind of A/W mapping.